# Does any infinitely generated group have no maximal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, maximal-subgroup

I've known that every finite group has maximal subgroups. And, use Zorn's Lemma, every finitely generated group has maximal subgroups.

Also, there are examples that have no maximal subgroups, like $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ or the Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$. They are both infinitely generated.

So I have this question that is every infinite generated group has no maximal subgroups? Or is there any counterexample?

Appreciate any suggestions in advance.

Comment: These are answers to the question, not just comments. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group of nonzero real numbers under multiplication is not finitely generated and has a maximal proper subgroup consisting of the positive numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Given any group $G$ and a finite group $H$ we have that $G\times H$ has a maximal subgroup. More precisely $G\times M$ is such subgroup for a maximal subgroup $M$ in $H$.

More generally the same will apply to any group $G$ that has a finite quotient $G/H$. Because there is one-to-one correspondence (which preserves inclusions) between subgroups of $G/H$ and subgroups of $G$ containing $H$. In particular every free group has a maximal subgroups, regardless of rank or cardinality.